# Lightning component to launch the screen flow

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, visual-workflow, aura

I am trying to launch a flow from a lightning component which is a button like below

Lightning Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
    <aura:attribute name="updateCase" type="Case" default="{'sobjectType':'Case'}"/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Change Owner" onclick="{!c.callOwnerChangeFlow}"  /> 
     <lightning:flow aura:id="OwnerChangeFlow" onstatuschange="{!c.statusChange}"/>     
    <lightning:spinner aura:id="mySpinner" alternativeText="Processing.." title="Processing.." variant="brand" size="large" class="slds-hide"/>
</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
    callOwnerChangeFlow : function(c, e, h) {
        h.callOwnerChange_helper(c,e,h);
    },        
    statusChange: function(c, e, h) {
        h.statusChange_helper(c,e,h);
    },
    
})
```

Helper

```
({
    callOwnerChange_helper: function(c, e, h) {
        var flow = c.find("OwnerChangeFlow");
        var userId = $A.get( "$SObjectType.CurrentUser.Id" );
        var inputVariables = [
            {
                name:"varCaseId",
                type:"String",
                value:c.get("v.recordId")
            }];         
        flow.startFlow("Transfer_to_CS_User", inputVariables);
    },
    
    statusChange_helper : function (component, event, helper) {
        if (event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED_SCREEN" || event.getParam('status') === "FINISHED") {
            window.location.reload();
            var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
            toastEvent.setParams({
                title: "Success!",
                message: "Successfull!",
                type: "success"
            });
           toastEvent.fire();
        } 
        else if (event.getParam('status') === "ERROR") {
            component.set("v.hasError", true);
        }
    }})
```

The flow is launched successfully when I click on the lightning component button but the issue is the flow screen is shown like this n the same page below the button

[image]

How can I launch the flow in to a new tab when the lightning component is clicked

Comment: No need to add `_helper` suffix in every helper method.

Comment: What do you mean by new tab? Have you created a custom tab for that? Or is it opening in a `console app`?

Comment: @NagendraSingh I want either the flow to be opened in the new browser tab/ in a console app tab. Or atleast open in a pop-up instead of showing the same screen

Comment: @itzmukeshy sure will follow.. Can you please suggest how the flow can be fired in to anew browser tab/ pop up instead of same screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modal would be very easy in this case.

Create a new component named as `LightningFlow`

```
<aura:component description="LightningFlow" implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction"
                access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="testAttr" type="String"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" action="{!c.doInit}" value="{!this}"/>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
</aura:component>
```

`Controller as :`

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper){
        alert(component.get('v.testAttr'));
        const flow = component.find("flowData");
        flow.startFlow("CreateAccountViaFlow");
    }
});
```

Then from your main component just call this component as a `modal`

```
<aura:attribute type="Boolean" name="ismodalClicked"/>
<lightning:button onclick="{!c.openmodal}">Start Flow</lightning:button>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.ismodalClicked}">
    <div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="header43" aura:id="Modalbox" class="slds-modal">
        <div class="slds-modal__container">
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <button class="slds-button slds-modal__close slds-button--icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick="{!c.closeModal}">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h2 id="header43" class="slds-text-heading--medium">Test Modal</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium">
                <div>
                    <c:LightningFlow testAttr="123"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
<div class="slds-backdrop " aura:id="Modalbackdrop"></div>
```

Controller :

```
closeModal:function(component,event,helper){
    component.set('v.ismodalClicked', false);
    var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
    var cmpBack = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpBack,'slds-backdrop--open');
    $A.util.removeClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
},
openmodal: function(component,event,helper) {
    component.set('v.ismodalClicked', true);
    var cmpTarget = component.find('Modalbox');
    var cmpBack = component.find('Modalbackdrop');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpTarget, 'slds-fade-in-open');
    $A.util.addClass(cmpBack, 'slds-backdrop--open');
}
```

Now your flow opens up as a modal, if you want to pass values then you can pass via attributes etc, as the modal is the child component of your main component.

**UPDATE**

To pass value from parent to modal you can make use of attribute.

From parent change to `<c:LightningFlow testAttr="123"/>`

In your `LightningFlow` component just define the same attribute.

```
<aura:attribute name="testAttr" type="String"/>
```

Now you can access the attribute via `component.get('v.testAttr')`.  Check code above.

Comment: This is great, thanks Can you please give an example how to pass the recordID from the main component to the modal thatcan be used by the flow

Comment: Updated that in `UPDATE` section of my answer.