# Display a flow inside another flow keeping the original flow in the background?

Tags: visual-workflow, aura

I have a flow running. When a person clicks a button I want to open a modal and run a separate flow keeping the other flow in the background. So when the user closes the modal they can continue with the main flow.

What I did was create an aura component and trigger that from my main flow. Then the aura component launches my sub-flow.

The problem I encounter is that Salesforce navigates to that sub-flow and leaves my main flow. Is there a way to contain the sub-flow in the aura modal and not navigate away from the main flow?

Similarly if you are on a record page and launch a flow from an action button it will open in a modal and when you complete the flow the modal closes and you are still on the record page.

Comment: A flow can call another flow (a "sub-flow"), but the user still has to navigate in and out of the subflow using normal means. You can't have a flow on top of a flow, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @sfdcfox I got it to work. My initial trouble was that I was working with a LWC. I had to wrap the LWC in an Aura. Then trigger that from the main flow. Then when the user clicked on a button in the LWC that would bubble to the Aura which would then start another flow(the sub-flow) into a modal. This way I am still in the main flow and the sub-flow at the same time. When the user completes the sub-flow they can continue interacting with the main flow.

Comment: Oh, cool. You should definitely document that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMYinUAH) package which gave me hope but I didn't want to install a package for something so trivial.

I also found [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327120/lightning-component-to-launch-the-screen-flow) thread really helpful which re-assured me that I was taking the right path.

My problem was never the flow going to the sub-flow and navigating out of the page. I had a LWC(in the main flow) so when I was navigating to the sub-flow I had to go through an aura which would mean for the main flow to navigate out of the LWC in order to go to the aura to launch the sub-flow.

Below I am sharing my solution. I have broken down the aura work into 2 components for logical separation. Also everything starts with the `Main_Flow` which is calling in on the `Aura_Container`. I am not sharing a screenshot as my `Main_Flow` has a lot more going on in it. Also `SomeAttribute` is just a value I am passing from the `Main_Flow` into the Aura->LWC. Basically something the LWC needs from the `Main_Flow`. Also I am not sharing the CSS since that is beyond the ask in this question.

**Aura Container HTML**

```
<aura:component description="auraContainer" implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="SomeAttribute" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="isShowSubFlow" type="Boolean" default="False"/>
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.isShowSubFlow}">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="close-button" onclick="{!c.handleCloseModal}"></div>
            <div class="modal-title">Some Title</div>
            <c:auraFlowStart />
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:if>
<c:theLwc
        someAttribute="{!v.SomeAttribute}"
        onisshowsubflow="{!c.getIsShowSubFlow}"
></c:theLwc>
</aura:component>
```

**Aura Container Controller**

```
({
    getIsShowSubFlow: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.isShowSubFlow",event.getParam('isShowSubFlow'));
    },
    handleCloseModal : function(cmp, event) {
        cmp.set('v.isShowSubFlow', false);
    }
});
```

**Aura Flow Start HTML**

```
<aura:component description="auraFlowStart" access="global">
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData"/>
</aura:component>
```

**Aura Flow Start Controller**

```
({
    init : function (cmp) {
        var flow = cmp.find("flowData");
        flow.startFlow("My_Sub_Flow");
    }
});
```

**LWC HTML**

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="launch-modal-button" onclick={handleLaunchModal} ></div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**LWC JS**

```
@api someAttribute;
handleLaunchModal() {
    let isShowSubFlow= true;
    const isShowSubflowEvt = new CustomEvent("isshowsubflow", {
      detail: { isShowSubFlow }
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(isShowSubflowEvt);
}
```